# DRY array in php

Tags: php, arrays, dry

Hello I am trying to apply the DRY concept to my program which now has over 3000 lines of codes just because i have been repeating myself a lot.

I have this array:

```
// prepare the sales payload
$sales_payload = array(
    'organization_id' => $getOrg['data'][0]['id'],
    'contact_id' => $contact_id,
    'status' => 'Open',
    'responsible_employee_id' => 'employee:50c76c15262b12d36d44e34a3f0f8c3d',
    'source' => array(
    'id' => $source['data'][0]['id'],
    'name' => $source['data'][0]['name'],
    ),
    'subject' => " ".str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])." - "."Online marketing Duitsland",
    'start_date' => date("Y-m-d"), // set start date on today
    'expected_closing_date' => date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date("Y-m-d")."+ 14 days")), // set expected closing date 2 weeks from now
    'chance_to_score' => '10%',
    'expected_revenue' => 0, //set the expected revenue
    'note' => $_POST['order_comments'],
    'progress' => array(
    'id'=>'salesprogress:200a53bf6d2bbbfe' //fill a valid salesprogress id to set proper sales progress 
    ),

  "custom_fields" => [["voorstel_diensten"=>implode("-",$online_marketing_check)]],

);
```

Is there a way I can dynamically change certain fields only instead of copying the whole thing and manually changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a function that clones the array and changes it

```
function arrayClone($args){
    $sales_payload = array(
        'organization_id' => $getOrg['data'][0]['id'],
        'contact_id' => $contact_id,
        'status' => 'Open',
        'responsible_employee_id' => 'employee:50c76c15262b12d36d44e34a3f0f8c3d',
        'source' => array(
        'id' => $source['data'][0]['id'],
        'name' => $source['data'][0]['name'],
        ),
        'subject' => " ".str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])." - "."Online marketing Duitsland",
        'start_date' => date("Y-m-d"), // set start date on today
        'expected_closing_date' => date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date("Y-m-d")."+ 14 days")), // set expected closing date 2 weeks from now
        'chance_to_score' => '10%',
        'expected_revenue' => 0, //set the expected revenue
        'note' => $_POST['order_comments'],
        'progress' => array(
        'id'=>'salesprogress:200a53bf6d2bbbfe' //fill a valid salesprogress id to set proper sales progress 
        ),

      "custom_fields" => [["voorstel_diensten"=>implode("-",$online_marketing_check)]],

    );

    return array_replace_recursive($sales_payload, $args);
}
```

How tu use it:

```
$a = arrayClone(['status' => 'Closed', 'contact_id' => 5]);
$b = arrayClone(['status' => 'Closed Now', 'contact_id' => 20]);
```

Comment: Or may be set a default array and overwrite particular fields as required.